# Allow logged in user to click its row

Tags: android, listview

I am struggling with the following. I have a list view showing users in that belong to a team. The rows contain the user's knickname and its number of steps he walked since every last midnight using Google fit SDK.

[image: Team Table]

So you see that Cerberus 33 walked 2342 steps and Lenovo 0.

I want the logged in user Cerberus 33 in my phone,to click to only one row i.e. the first one,so he can see an alert dialog with a leave team button.

Here is the part of my code.

I am retrieve the logged in username and password from another activity by using shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences settings =   
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    username = settings.getString("username", "");
    password = settings.getString("password", "");
```

And now I compare this logged in username with the username I get from the database via the volley library.

```
private void getTeamPlayers(final String teamId, final String username, 
final String password) {
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";


    final HashMap<String, String> postParams1 = new HashMap<String,  
 String>();


    postParams1.put("team_id", teamId);
    postParams1.put("username", username);
    postParams1.put("password", password);


    Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener;
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(postParams1);

    //{"team_id":"189","password":"xxx","username":"Cerberus 33"}
    final JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq1 = new 
    JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.URL_GET_TEAM, jsonObject,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());

                    try {

                        Log.d("JsonArray", response.toString());


                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject item = 
                        response.getJSONObject(i);
                            userType = item.getString("user_type");
                            userName = item.getString("username");
                            TeamPlayers tm = new TeamPlayers();


                tm.setLatestSteps(item.getString("latest_steps"));
                            tm.setNickname(item.getString("nickname"));

                tm.setUserType(item.getString("user_type"));
                            String latestSteps = 
                item.getString("latest_steps");
                            String userType = 
                item.getString("user_type");
                            int totalSteps =    
                Integer.valueOf(latestSteps);

                            Log.d("total", "steps: " + totalSteps);
                            teamPlayersList.add(tm);


                            Log.d("Username",username);
                            Log.d("UserName",userName);

                   //comparing username(loggin user)
                   //with userName(username retrieved by database)
                   if(username.equals(userName)) {
                                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new 
                   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void 
                   onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
                   position, long id) {


               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's me!!",         
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
              });

            }
         }

   } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
   }
     //pDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }


    };


    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq1, 
    tag_json_obj);

 VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).
 addToRequestQueue(jsonObjRequest);

}
```

Here is the output.

```
     [{"latest_steps":"2342","user_type":"LEADER","nickname":"Cerberus   
     33","username":"cerberus_33@hotmail.com"}, 
     {"latest_steps":"0","user_type":"LEADER","nickname":"Lenovo",
     "username":"lenovo@gmail.com"}]
      steps: 2342
     D/Username﹕ cerberus_33@hotmail.com
     D/UserName﹕ cerberus_33@hotmail.com
     D/total﹕ steps: 0
     D/Username﹕ cerberus_33@hotmail.com
     D/UserName﹕ lenovo@gmail.com
     D/TAG﹕ {"team_steps":"2342"}
     D/team steps﹕ 2342
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want the user to have only the ability to click on his own row. I suppose you have an adapter to build row of your `ListView`. In this adapter override the method `boolean isEnabled(int position)` to enabled only the desired row.

**EDIT**

In your adapter add the following

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (position is user row) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will allow the user to clik only on the row where you return true (position is user row). Then you can use `listView.setOnItemClickListener()` as usual.

**EDIT**

This is what I do but both rows are disabled now.

```
 adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplication(), teamPlayersList){
                                @Override
                                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                                    String currentName = teamPlayersList.get(position).getUserName();//i'm not sur this is the right getter but it should be
                                    //the spirit is to compare the name of the user of this row to the name of the user you want to enabled
                                    if (currentName.equals(userName)) {

                                        return true;
                                    } else {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            }
                        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new 

                        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>  
                        parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It's 
                        me",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Yeap I have an adapter.

Comment: teamPlayersList = new ArrayList<>();
 adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplication(), teamPlayersList)

Comment: I edit my answer to be more detailed. Tell me if you don't undestand or if i'm not responding to your problem.

Comment: Ok. I can enable only the first row to be clickable. But what if my username Cerberus 33 is in the next row? The position of the logged in users in the list row is based on steps. That's why Cerberus 33 is first for now.

Comment: Well you have to put a little extra effort in the `isEnabled` method. For instance you can pass  the rank of your user or his name to your adapter and use this information to decide if a specific row is enabled.

Comment: I understand now. Pass the username of the logged in user. But you can't compared like if(position==username). position is an int and username a string.

Comment: I see. I modify and approve your edit. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see your logs. The issue is that apprently the `teamPlayersList.get(position).getUserName()` returns `null`. You should check that every row is corresponding to a team play"er with a name. The goal of the compraraison is to see if the row display the user or another user. So you should compare the userName with the name of user display in row at `position`.

Comment: Ok I fixed it. Thank you my friend for your patience:).